# Syntax error on token "{", { expected after this token

Tags: java, syntax, syntax-error

I don't understand this syntax error at all, I'm pretty knew to Java and I'm trying to follow the instructions on my assignment but I have no clue what stops them from working

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Point {
   private double xCoord;
   private double yCoord;

   public double getxCoord(){ //accessors
      return xCoord;
   }
   public double getyCoord(){
      return yCoord;
   }
   Point defaultConstructor = new Point(){  // (the error is one this line) default constructor - I have to make a point object in the Main with this
      xCoord = 0;                         
      yCoord = 0;
      System.out.println("Testing default constructor");
   }
   Point twoArgConstructor = new Point( 3.2, 4.5){ // (the error is one this line) two-argument constructor
      xCoord = 3.2;
      yCoord = 4.5;
      System.out.println("Testing two-argument constructor");
   }

   public String toString (){
      System.out.println("("+xCoord+", "+yCoord+")");   
   }

   public void defaultConstructor() {
   }

   public void twoArgConstructor() {
   }

}
```

this is the main class if it helps

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FrazierLab9{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Point point1 = new Point();
        Point point2 = new Point();

        point1.defaultConstructor();
        point1.toString();
        point2.twoArgConstructor();
        point2.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  ```getxCoord(``` is missing the closing ```)```

Comment: Compare the declaration of `getxCoord` with the declaration of `getyCoord`. You're missing a `)` at the end of the parameter list.

Comment: Additionally, once you've fixed the syntax error, you've got a problem that `defaultConstructor` and `twoArgConstructor` are *fields* (which will cause a stack overflow) but you're calling them as if they're *methods* in `main`. I suspect you intended to make them methods, and ideally don't use an anonymous class in the implementation...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close a parenthesis when declaring the getxCoord method

```
public double getxCoord({ //accessors
  return xCoord;
}
```

Even if you don't use an IDE, the compiler should give you more information about the problem. For the code above, executing

```
javac Point.java
```

I got

```
Point.java:7: error: illegal start of type
public double getxCoord({ //accessors
                        ^
Point.java:7: error: ')' expected
public double getxCoord({ //accessors
                         ^
...
```

which shows that the errors were detected in the 7th line onwards.

---

### after OP's edit

These are not constructors. You need to define the constructors inside the Point class, then construct Point **objects** from the Point **class** using `Point p = new Point()` or `Point p = new Point(3.4,5.6)` elsewhere (e.g. in the main class). You can then call any methods you want from the objects.

```
public Point(){
  this.xCoord = 0;                         
  this.yCoord = 0;
  System.out.println("Testing default constructor");
}
public Point(double x, double y){ 
  this.xCoord = x;
  this.yCoord = y;
  System.out.println("Testing two-argument constructor");
}

...
```

Comment: My bad, I guess I typed it in wrong or something. But my getxCoord has closed parentheses. My problem is with the constructors + the last bracket on line 33 has a red on it too (showing 4 syntax errors - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration, Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody, Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration, Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody)

Comment: your edit has changed the problem completely. You first need to understand what a constructor is, these constructor*.. constructs are not valid Java code.